# Отсчет времени до завтрашнего дня

Tags: javascript

Есть скрипт, который рассчитывает время до завтрашнего дня. Под каждой строкой я написал комментарии. Мне не понятно, как рассчитывается  кол-во минут: `(seconds % 3600) / 60`. И кол-во секунд: `(seconds % 3600) % 60`.

```
var tomorrow = new Date().setHours(24, 0, 0);

(function foo() {
  var now = new Date();

  // Сколько секунд осталось до завтра.
  var seconds = parseInt(tomorrow - now) / 1000;

  // 3600 - кол-во секунд в часе. Сколько часов осталось до завтра
  var hh = parseInt( seconds / 3600 );

 //
  var mm = parseInt( (seconds % 3600) / 60 );

  var ss = parseInt( (seconds % 3600) % 60 );

  document.body.innerHTML = hh + ":" + mm + ":" + ss ;

  setTimeout(foo, 1000);
})();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Оператор %](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#%D0%94%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D0%BE_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8E_()) возвращает остаток от деления. Таким образом результат

```
seconds % 3600
```

это количество секунд неполного часа

здесь `(seconds % 3600) / 60` они переводятся в минуты

а тут `(seconds % 3600) % 60` по такому же принципу получаются секунды не полной минуты.

---

#### Пример:

Возьмем для примера `seconds=4000`

В этом случае получаем один час (3600) плюс неполный час - сколько минут меньше 60

```
seconds % 3600 = 4000 % 3600 = 400
```

Проверяем сколько это составляет минут

```
400 / 60 = 6.666666666666667
```

отбрасываем дробную часть - получаем 6 минут.

Осталось узнать количество секунд

```
400 % 60 = 40
```

Итого: 1 полный час, 6 полных минут, 40 секунд

Comment: Как понять, неполного часа? Если убрать деление на 60 и оставить `seconds % 3600`, то в самом начале часа будет 3600, т.е. полный час.

Comment: @Aleksandr, сейчас попробую примером дополнить :)

Comment: хорошо, спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

А не проще отдельно считать часы, минуты и секунды?

Примерно так:

```
var now, hh, mm, ss;
now = new Date();
now.setSeconds(now.getSeconds() - 1);
// Корректируем время на одну секунду, иначе будет результат меньше на одну секунду
hh = 23 - now.getHours();
mm = 59 - now.getMinutes();
ss = 59 - now.getSeconds();
```

Дополнительно можно добавить правильное отображение времени при условии, что сейчас время *00:00:00*

```
if (!(hh || mm || ss)) hh = 24;
```

Чтобы часы, минуты и секунды отображались с ведущими нулями можно сделать так:

```
str = ('0' + hh).slice(-2) +
    ':' + ('0' + mm).slice(-2) + 
    ':' + ('0' + ss).slice(-2);
```

```js
setInterval(function() {
  var now, hh, mm, ss;
  now = new Date();
  now.setSeconds(now.getSeconds() - 1);
  // Корректируем время на одну секунду, иначе будет результат меньше на одну секунду
  hh = 23 - now.getHours();
  mm = 59 - now.getMinutes();
  ss = 59 - now.getSeconds();
  if (!(hh || mm || ss)) hh = 24;
  document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML =
    ('0' + hh).slice(-2) +
    ':' + ('0' + mm).slice(-2) +
    ':' + ('0' + ss).slice(-2);
}, 500);
```

```html
<div id="countdown"></div>
```

Comment: Проще, но мне хотелось бы узнать, как рассчитывается в приведенном мной примере.

Comment: У вас есть разница в секундах. `seconds % 3600` это разница в секундах в пределах часа. Делим ее на 60, берем целое - получаем минуты. Берем остаток от деления на 60 - получаем секунды. Вроде все прозрачно.

Comment: @tutankhamun, похоже расчеты не совсем правильные, посмотрите пример для `23:00:00` - получите: `h=1`,`mm=60`,`ss=60`, и для `23:59:59` - `h=1`,`mm=1`, `ss=1`

Comment: @tutankhamun, да в ответе, дополнил комментарий выше примером

Comment: @tutankhamun, вообще говоря все равно не правильно :) проверьте на тех же примерах

Comment: @Grundy Теперь правильно

Comment: @tutankhamun, ага, похоже на то :-) по крайней мере для этих примеров :)

Comment: теперь проблема с `"00:00:00"`, точнее _вероятно проблема_, я так понимаю должно показываться 24 часа, хотя, безусловно, поймать такой вариант довольно не просто, впрочем он воспроизводится и у топик стартера :)

Comment: @Grundy Для теста поймать-то легко `now = new Date('01/01/2016 00:00:00');` В реальных условиях - неправильное значение будет показано ровно секунду. Если это критично, можно специально обрабатывать это значение (подставлять `24:0:0`)

Comment: секунда это на самом деле очень мало :-) в любом случае думаю это не критично :)